# How may I reduce horizontal space between the two equations of the following?

Tags: spacing

The spacing is too much; I want *some* space between the equations, but not as much space as of the following. I would appreciate if someone could provide me with a coherent answer.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&+(+a)=+a,& &-(+a)=-a&\\
&+(-a)=-a,& &-(-a)=+a&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what will best meet your criterion of "not as much space" being taken between the two columns of equations. The following solution may fit the bill. It also results, incidentally, in better centering of the material -- which I take to be a criterion as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
+(+a)&=+a,& -(+a)&=-a\\
+(-a)&=-a,& -(-a)&=+a
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This would be perfect for me. I could doubtless continue with it.
I apologise for my question should have been altered as the space between the two columns of equations. Thank you very much for providing me an answer with coherence.

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa - Thanks. It's always good to know one is being coherent... :-)

Answer (score 7):

With `alignat` you control the space by yourself.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
+(+a)&=+a,& \qquad -(+a)&=-a\\
+(-a)&=-a,&       -(-a)&=+a
\end{alignat*}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
+(+a)&=+a,& \hspace{1in} -(+a)&=-a\\
+(-a)&=-a,&       -(-a)&=+a
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used the method you previously taught me to make space between these columns of equations. Unfortunately, I could not make them contracted as you did right now. This is the exact way in which the book I showed you had kept space. Thank you very much, Sir Harish!

Comment: @NisalKevinKotinkaduwa You are welcome. :)